# Copy build artifacts with gradle

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, aar

I use gradle to build android library and push it to remote maven repository. Is there some way to get resulting `pom` and `aar` files and copy it, for example, to root of the project?

Here is the task for publishing to maven (it's in library project `build.gradle`)

```
uploadArchives {
    configuration = configurations.archives
    repositories.mavenDeployer {

        repository(url: constants.snapshotUrl) {
            authentication(userName: userName, password: password)
            pom.groupId = constants.groupId
            pom.artifactId = constants.libUIArtifactIdName
            pom.version = constants.projectVersion
        }

        pom.whenConfigured { pom ->
            pom.dependencies.forEach { dep ->
                if (dep.getVersion() == "unspecified") {
                    dep.setGroupId(constants.groupId)
                    dep.setVersion(constants.projectVersion)
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using `maven` plugin? If so you'll find generated poms under `${project.buildDir}/poms` and artifacts e.g. from `install` task configuration.

Comment: @Opal or, maybe, I can do this with uploadArchives.doLast?

Comment: Probably, it can be done this way.

Comment: Thanks! If you can rewrite your comment as an answer, I will gladly accept it.

Comment: Added the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using `maven` plugin? If so you'll find generated poms under `${project.buildDir}/poms` and artifacts e.g. from `install` task configuration.

Also `doLast` for `uploadArchives` can be probably utilised.